# Two NSCollectionView scroll synchronization

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit

I got a two instances of NSCollectionView in one controller and want to scroll it both synchronously. So i implemented a custom NSSrollView class and assigned it to enclosing scrollView to one of those collections. Here is the code:

```
protocol CustomScrollViewDelegate: class
{

    func customScrollView(_ CustomScrollView: CustomScrollView, didScrollWith event: NSEvent)

}

class CustomScrollView: NSScrollView
{

    weak var delegate: CustomScrollViewDelegate?

override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)
{
    switch event.phase
    {
        case NSEvent.Phase.changed:
            delegate?.customScrollView(self, didScrollWith: event)

        default:
            break
    }

    switch event.momentumPhase
    {
        case NSEvent.Phase.changed:
            delegate?.customScrollView(self, didScrollWith: event)

        default:
            break
    }

    super.scrollWheel(with: event)
   }
}
```

In second collectionView i conforms to CustomScrollViewDelegate protocol and do:

```
self.collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.scrollWheel(with: event)
```

Actually, it works, but not smooth at all. When scrolling is slow, the deferences between offset in booth collections are minimal. But if you do flick gesture - it looks awful. Here is the video:

https://youtu.be/RzbKFYVPQhY

Is there any way to achieve smooth synchronous scrolling on booth collections?

Comment: If memory serves me (and this is a long time ago), Apple published a sample project showing how to do synchronized scrolling. You might try to find that. I'd just start by looking for sample projects using `NSScrollView`.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Is this the sample code: [Synchronizing Scroll Views}(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003537-SW5)?

Comment: That looks like it! They key here is that one view observes the changes in bounds of the other view's clip view. This should always work, no matter how or when the scroll view scrolls. It looks like you're trying to intercept the scroll-wheel events; but that's only one of about a billion different ways the scroll view can be scrolled.

Comment: The most simpler and suitable solution for me was to refactor code that way so i can wrap both elements (left and right) in one collectionViewItem